# can't run helm command in container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I built a docker image to run `helm` in container.

```
FROM alpine:edge

ARG HELM_VERSION=2.9.0
ENV URL="https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-v${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz"

RUN apk add --no-cache curl && \
    curl -L ${URL} |tar xvz && \
    cp linux-amd64/helm /usr/bin/helm && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/helm && \
    rm -rf linux-amd64 && \
    apk del curl

WORKDIR /apps

ENTRYPOINT ["helm"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

I have put `kubeconfig` to default path `~/.kube/config`, and I am fine to run helm commands locally

But when run helm command within container, i got below error:

> $ docker run -ti --rm -v ~/.kube:/root/.kube -v $(pwd):/apps helm list
>
> Error: Get https://xxxx.yl4.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dhelm%2Cname%3Dtiller: dial tcp 10.xxx.7.xxx:443: i/o timeout

Anything I can check?

#### Updates

Tried next day, it works without any changes.

Comment: `But when run helm command within container, i got below error:` where did you run it. I mean inside the cluster ot on your workstation but inside the docker ?

Comment: The file `~/.kube/config` has defined the kubernetes API url, my understanding is, if I can run `helm` directly from my laptop, I should be fine to run it in container, which running on my laptop as well.

Comment: yes if you have the same `./kube` folder.